# Remote User Logging Information on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

Currently We have one server with Windows Server 2008 r2 OS. Now there are many people used to this server from remote location. Now I have some knowledge of WMI classes which gives information about user login (Win32_LogonSession) but it not gives what I want. Like I want user login time, logout time, remote location IP address ( so that I can guess it is desirable location or not ).

Please help me if I can this with help of WMI

Answer (score 0):

scanning remote event logs with PowerShell, here's an article that recommends Get-WinEvent rather than Get-EventLog:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/24/use-powershell-cmdlet-to-filter-event-log-for-easy-parsing.aspx

Get-WinEvent apparently does filtering on the remote computer before pulling results over the network, which should be faster. However Get-WinEvent requires Vista or later.

Referred from http://social.technet.microsoft.com

Comment: But it is still not give the IP address of Remote User. I am more focusing on IP address so that my purpose has been satisfy.